Переходы между страницами WordPress
Всем привет. Не понимаю как сделать переход на другую страницу в WordPress с этого линка
li class="nav__item">a class="nav__links-item" href="">gets</a>/li>. Мне нужно открыть другую страницу ("Gets")

Возможно дубликат вопроса

Вы о чем вообще? В WordPress есть навигационное меню, которое заполняется из админ панели, в чем проблема?

.. и причём тут мультисайт..
